# How to identify fake likes on a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way (through API, observation, algorithm) to say if a significant amount (>50%) of the likes of a landing page are fake?

APPENDIX: Ok, I got the first downgrade. Why? Do you think there is no answer to this question? I can tell you that there is no existing online service available to check facebook page reliability and why should that not be a reliable question? Everybody is talking about fake profile detection, but that is not what I need.

Actually there is one that pretends to be able: BING
http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2011/05/17/social-and-search-a-small-business-primer.aspx
But I doupt. Do you?

Comment: I guess the downgrade was because you did not mention any research effort yet, not because of the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a way to identify fake users actually... not fake likes... currently Facebook does not provide us a way to do this. I'm sure they have internal methods to check this but we can't do it by ourselves.

Comment: I understand your assumption, somehow the fake account detection is a possible second step: But its not for a page I own myself, it is for a page of a product (for example). Main Problem is probably that you will not see **who** liked the page (only for the likes of persons that are your own friends). So you possibly could not go for the fake accounts?

Comment: oh.. so you are talking about gathering this information without being the administrator of the page? without "owning" the likes?

Comment: If the only way to determine real likes from fake likes, one has to gather the accounts who liked the page? At least 99 accounts are known (if you use the show_faces option), if you generate a "like-link-page" on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ . But for a certain time, those 99 accounts are not exchanged with other accounts and more than 99 accounts are not viewable.